# How to increase a version value when inserting new data?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres, there is a table with a version(bigint) is used for versioning the data, I want it works in both manual sql and java framework.

When using a java framework(Spring Data, JPA, etc), the version(for example, annotated with `@Version` in JPA) will be updated automatically.

But how to use a simple sql to done the same work, I have searched the stackoverflow and get there are solution, such as trigger/function to resolve this issue. But when using framework and pure sql together, I do not want to destroy the functionality of the framework.

I tried to use the following sql, failed due to the bad reference of `version`.

```sql
INSERT INTO customers(name, age, street, city, zip, version) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, version+1) 
RETURNING id
```

The version is defined as a `bigint` with default `0`, I want to set it to a new value(existing version + 1) automatically when inserting and updating(`update customers set ...`).

Comment: What are you trying to "increase" exactly? What "version"? There is no reference value for an `INSERT`. Do you mean a serial / IDENTITY / "autoincrement" column? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860 Gaps are ok? Please clarify. And always disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Shouldn't the version increase during an `UPDATE`? Why `INSERT`?

Answer (score 0):

> ... a table with a version(bigint) is used for versioning the data, I want it works in both manual sql and java framework.

If you want it to work with *ad hoc* SQL, then a trigger is about the *only* reliable way.
Use the "old" values in the update trigger to set the "new" value.

I'm curious to know what this field gets you, other than an ever increasing number that would *only* be useful if you retained every "version" of every record in a "history" or "audit" table.